# Controlling the output in ServiceStack.Swagger-UI for my REST api

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I am exporting RESTful API via ServiceStack + Swagger plugin, version is 4.0.33.0.

1. How can I use Markdown for method description?  I tried to put Markdown text into `ServiceStack.RouteAttribute.Notes`, but it does not take effect when I look into the Swagger-UI from ServiceStack and the raw text is presented there,
2. How can I output the model schema of response in ServiceStack?  `ServiceStack.ApiResponseAttribute' class seems lack of fields.

Comment: I can only give a partial answer, so I'll keep it in a comment - At the moment, Swagger-UI does not support Markdown text, but it should be added in the future. Feel free to open an issue about it.

Comment: I see Markdown is supported in http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Comment: Two entirely separate projects.